# Google Sheets Add-on onSelectionChange client side

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making an add-on for Google Sheets. I would like to listen to an event in the frontend (in the javascript side) that's triggered on cell selection change.

As I didn't find any solution by googling the problem. I came up with the idea to make a request every 100 ms to detect if the selection has changed. the code would look like:

```js
 
var lastSelection; 
function onSelectionChange(e){
    lastSelection = e ; 
}
function onCheckSelection(e){

    if(e != lastSelection){ // not the actual implementation  
        onSelectionChange(e); 
    }
}
setTimeout( function() { 
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(onCheckSelection)    
    .getCurrentSelection(); // where getCurrentSelection is a server function that returns the range of currently selected cell 

} , 100);
```

But I am not sure if there is a better idea.

Comment: Actually onSelectionChange trigger comes from the server

Comment: Can you add in some context? Why do you need this in the client side? (it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an onSelectionChange() that fires when a user changes their selection on a sheet.

[onSelectionChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

But there is no client side event for that change.

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I know that there is such a trigger but I actually need it on the client side.

Comment: There are a lot of client side events but unfortunately that is not one of them.

Comment: Actually I didn't find any of the client side events can you show me where I can find the documentation please ?

Comment: I added links in my answer

Comment: You said that there are a lot of client side events, but all of those in the links are server side events, am I mistaken ?

Comment: Yes those are all server side events.  I assumed that you already know all of the typical javascript clientside events or no where to find them.  Google Apps Script runs on a server not on a browser.

Comment: Of course I can always use javascript events. But what I am looking for is official implementation for such an event in the frontside. thanks for your help , appreciate it.

Comment: I think I still misunderstand your intentions and your current code does not provide me with enough information to predict your intended course.

Comment: ok in my add-in I am serving html file which contains a javascript file. In this javascript file I would like to have an event that gets triggered when the user changes the selection. the code is a proposal for a not ideal implementation for such an event.

Comment: Well you use the term Google Doc Spreadsheet Add-on and there is an onSelectionChange in Google Spreadsheets but not in Google Documents so that is one thing I don't understand.  Your most recent statement regarding serving upon html with Javascript and wanting a way to sense a server side action from a clientside javascript doesn't seem possible since events on the clientside are generally tied to client actions and not server actions.  Normally clients side javascript requires an http request to get information from a server and then it is only provided as a response to the request.

Comment: You seem to want the impossible.

Comment: Sorry for the misuse of names I edited the question.  yes I am always talking about Google Sheets. but what I don't understand is, after all the event is originally triggered in the client-side why I can't catch such an event.  when I say serving html I mean using `HtmlService` to eventually render my add-in in a sidebar. Which contains a javascript file that contains my add-in logic.

Comment: The event is not trigger on the client side.  Google App Script only runs on Google Servers not on your browswer.  There is no onSelectionChange trigger from the Google Servers to your clientside javascript.  You have to poll for the changes.

Comment: Is there any documentation explains the architecture and the technology behind Google Sheet ?

Comment: Not that I now of.